# In jQuery, is there any way to only bind a click once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax app that will run functions on every interaction.  I'd like to be able to run my setup function each time so all my setup code for that function remains encapsulated.  However, binding elements more than once means that the handler will run more than once, which is obviously undesirable. Is there an elegant way in jQuery to call bind on an element more than once without the handler being called more than once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could attach the event to `document` with the `one()` function:

```
$(document).one('click', function(e) {
    // initialization here
});
```

Once run, this event handler is removed again so that it will not run again. However, if you need the initialization to run **before** the click event of some other element, we will have to think of something else. Using `mousedown` instead of `click` might work then, as the mousedown event is fired before the click event.

Comment: You're missing a `);` in there.

Comment: This will only solve his problem partially. Attaching events using `one` multiple times will still run multiple times, but once each.

Comment: @Chetan: I don't quite understand. There is only one `document` object (to which the event bubbles up), so how am I attaching the event multiple times?

Comment: @Tom see http://jsfiddle.net/P6aUT/2/ .. each time you click on `Attach click handler` and then click anywhere in the document, the attached event handler will get executed *once*. Also, attaching the event handler to document is no different from attaching it to any other element.

Comment: Reading the question again, it is not entirely clear to me. Why the need to bind an event handler to an element more than once?

Comment: @Tom - that is a good point. Binding the event handlers again because the Javascript initialization code needs to run on every interaction sounds like it would require a lot of patchwork. A better solution might be to reset the state of the application (including removing all event handlers as @Chetan suggested) to the initial state instead of trying to preventing binding the same handlers again.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, this does not seem like the correct answer for the reasons @chetansastry says.

Answer (score 12):

User jQuery `one` function like Tom said, but unbind the handler each time before binding again. It helps to have the event handler assigned to a variable than using an anonymous function.

```
 var handler = function(e) { // stuff };

 $('#element').unbind('click', handler).one('click', handler);

 //elsewhere
 $('#element').unbind('click', handler).one('click', handler);
```

You can also do `.unbind('click')` to remove all click handlers attached to an element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use .off() if unbind doesn't do the trick. Make sure the selector and event given to .off exactly match the ones initially provided to .on():

```
$("div.selector").off("click", "a.another_selector");    
$("div.selector").on("click", "a.another_selector", function(e){
```

This is what worked for me in resolving the same ajax reloading problem.

Comment: I like this because the $(element).unbind(event); solution would remove all events of the type (e.g. click) from the element, whereas this method just removes the one related to the selector in question and leaves others attached even if they share the same event type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Chetan Sastry is what you want. Basically just call a $(element).unbind(event); before every event.

So if you have a function like loadAllButtonClicks() that contains all the

```
$(element).on("click", function (){});
```

methods for each button on your page, and you run that every time a button is clicked, this will obviously produce more than one event for each button. To solve this just add

```
$(element).unbind(event);
```

before every

```
$(element).on("click", function (){});
```

and it will unbind all events to that element, then add the one click event.