# jQuery — trigger a live event only once per element on the page?

Tags: events, jquery

**Here's the scenario**

```
$("p").live('customEvent', function (event, chkSomething){ 
//this particular custom event works with live
    if(chkSomething){
        doStuff();
        // BUT only per element
        // So almost like a .one(), but on an elemental basis, and .live()?
    }
})
```

**Here's some background**

The custom event is from a [plugin called inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview#readme)

The actual issue is here http://syndex.me

1. In a nutshell, new tumblr posts are being infnitely scrolled via
   javascript hack (the only one out there for tumblr fyi.)
2. The inview plugin listens for new posts to come into the viewport, if the top of an image is shown, it makes it visible.
3. It's kinda working, but if you check your console at http://.syndex.me check how often the event is being fired
4. Maybe i'm also being to fussy and this is ok? Please let me know your professional opinion. but ideally i'd like it to stop doing something i dont need anymore.

**Some things I've tried that did not work:**

5. stopPropagation
6. .die();
7. Some solutions via S.O. didnt work either eg [In jQuery, is there any way to only bind a click once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947218/in-jquery-is-there-any-way-to-only-bind-a-click-once) or [Using .one() with .live() jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796207/using-one-with-live-jquery)

I'm pretty surprised as to why such an option isnt out there yet. Surely the .one() event is also needed for future elements too? #justsayin

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the element when the event happens, and only have the event happen on elements that don't have that class.

```
$("p:not(.nolive)").live(event,function(){
  $(this).addClass("nolive");
  dostuff();
});
```

Edit: Example from comments:

```
$("p").live(event,function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.data("live")) {
    return;
  }
  $this.data("live",true);
  doStuff();
});
```

Comment: Great idea Kevin; certainly functional :) I've started to shy away from using css tags in favor of the data object; I just don't really like repurposing css declarations, which could get us in trouble if 'nolive' (in this instance) ever ended up in the stylesheet.  Food for thought.

Comment: The only issue with using a data object is that it can't be filtered using a simple selector like this. You would end up just having an if statement like you have. I'll make an example.

Comment: True, true... programming is all about tradeoffs, is it not? :)

Comment: What is the $this = $(this) needed for?

Comment: Since we are using `$(this)` more than once, I cached it to reduce the processing required. It isn't required and doesn't make a difference in this case, it is just something I've become used to doing every time i use the same selection more than once.

Comment: Nice thanks for the tip. It's hard to choose a √ here, they are all good. I chose this one as it's got two options. You have no idea how many dud SO posts I created in the last 24hours to get to formulate the right question. My thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

This one works (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/KBT6m/1/)):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("p").live('customEvent', function(event, chkSomething) {
        //this particular custom event works with live
        if (chkSomething) {
            doStuff();
            // BUT only per element
            // So almost like a .one(), but on an elemental basis, and .live()?
            $(this).bind('customEvent', false);
        }
    });

    function doStuff() {
        window.alert('ran dostuff');
    };

    $('#content').append('<p>Here is a test</p>');

    $('p').trigger('customEvent', {one: true});
    $('p').trigger('customEvent', {one: true});
    $('p').trigger('customEvent', {one: true});
});
```

This should also work for your needs, although it's not as pretty :)

```js
$("p").live('customEvent', function (event, chkSomething){ 
    //this particular custom event works with live
    if(chkSomething && $(this).data('customEventRanAlready') != 1){
        doStuff();
        // BUT only per element
        // So almost like a .one(), but on an elemental basis, and .live()?
        $(this).data('customEventRanAlready', 1);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Kevin mentioned, you can accomplish this by manipulating the CSS selectors, but you actually don't have to use `:not()`. Here's an alternative method:

```
// Use an attribute selector like so. This will only select elements
// that have 'theImage' as their ONLY class. Adding another class to them
// will effectively disable the repeating calls from live()
$('div[class=theImage]').live('inview',function(event, visible, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
   if (visiblePartY=="top") {
      $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $(this).addClass('nolive');
      console.log("look just how many times this is firing")
   }
});
```

I used the actual code from your site. Hope that was okay.