# Jquery click function should not call again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an asp.net app in which I am using Jquery and I want if Jquery click function calls once then it should not be called again until a page load. The click function code is following

```
  $("#plblAgreeProblem").click(function(){

      var str = {
            problemID: $("#problemID").val(),
            empID : $("#empID").val()
      }

      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%= Url.Action("AgreeProblem", "Discussion")  %>",
                data: str,

                error: function(msg){
                    alert("error2" + msg);
                },
                success: function (msg) {

                    $("#ptxtDisAgreeProblem").empty();

                    $("#ptxtDisAgreeProblem").text(msg);

                }
            });
        })
```

Sorry for poor English.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, is there any way to only bind a click once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947218/in-jquery-is-there-any-way-to-only-bind-a-click-once)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `one` function:

```
$("#plblAgreeProblem").one('click', function(){ //...
```

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

**[docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your clikc handler add this:

```
$("#plblAgreeProblem").unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are generally correct, but keep in mind *when* you want to unbind the event. As soon as the user clicks it? or as soon as the ajax response returns successfully?

```
$("#plblAgreeProblem").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var str = {
        problemID: $("#problemID").val(),
        empID: $("#empID").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= Url.Action("
        AgreeProblem ", "
        Discussion ")  %>",
        data: str,

        error: function(msg) {
            alert("error2" + msg);
        },
        success: function(msg) {

            $("#ptxtDisAgreeProblem").empty();

            $("#ptxtDisAgreeProblem").text(msg);

            // do this unbind here, after the call has been made successfully.
            $this.unbind('click');

        }
    });


})
```